# Modal Window or confirm box in Form.onSubmit

Tags: java, wicket

In Form.onSubmit can I add a SimpleAttributeModifier to that form? Actually I have a situation where the onSubmit method of the form look like this:

```
@Override
public void onSubmit() {
    //some code
    if (some_condition) {
        //here I want to show Javascript confirm box or wicket modal window
        //but I can not get any AjaxRequestTarget here to show that modal
        add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("onSubmit", "return confirm('confirm msg')"));
    }
    //some code
}
```

It is not working. Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying will definitely not work, as the `onSubmit()` method is not called in time.  It is a server-side method called when the form is submitted.  In order to show a confirm dialogue, you want some javascript executed on the client before the form is sent back from the client to the server.

You need the attachment of javascript to happen when the html is rendered, so that it's there to be called when the user clicks the submit button.

It can of course be done.  I don't have my own code for it handy, but I think [this example](http://wicketbyexample.com/wicket-ajax-confirmation-modal-window/) should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I am new to wicket. Can you please explain "You need the attachment of javascript to happen when the html is rendered."

Comment: Unfortunately the link to the example is not valid anymore.

Comment: This is an old enough question and answer that how you do this in wicket has radically changed by now.  

A new answer for how you do it in current version wicket might be nice, but I can't do it right now.